# How to build carousel tailwind css flexbox with react slick

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, react-slick

I first time build carousel with `tailwind css` and `react slick`.

`Post` component has own height `calc(100vh - 65px)`. after I use `flexbox` like this:

```
data.map((i, index) => (
              <div
                key={index}
                className="min-h-screen h-direct w-full mb-5 flex flex-col items-center p-2 md:px-6"
                ref={index === data.length - 1 ? lastBookElementRef : null}
              >
                <Post
                  index={index}
                  item={i}
                  isModal={false}
                  t={t}
                  user={user}
                />
              </div>

            ))
```

on Post page:

```
/* eslint-disable jsx-a11y/media-has-caption */
/* eslint-disable jsx-a11y/img-redundant-alt */
/* eslint-disable react/jsx-props-no-multi-spaces */
/* eslint-disable no-unused-expressions */
import { ArrowLeftOutlined, ArrowRightOutlined, DeleteOutlined, FileSyncOutlined, HeartFilled, HeartOutlined, LikeOutlined, UserOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import axios from 'axios';
import Link from 'next/link';
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player';
import Slider from 'react-slick';
import { BallTriangle } from 'react-loader-spinner';
import calculateTime from '../calculateTime';
import { useSocket } from '../context/socket';
import Modal from './Modal';

const Post = ({ item, isModal, user, t }) => {
  const [myLikes, setMyLikes] = useState(item.likes);
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const socket = useSocket();
  const parentRef = useRef(null);
  const scrollRef = useRef(null);

  const [imageLoading, setImageLoading] = useState(item.files);

  const imageLoaded = (id) => {
    setImageLoading((prev) => prev.filter((t) => t.path !== id));
  };

  const [currentItem, setCurrentItem] = useState(0);
  const settings = {
    dots: false,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 500,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    initialSlide: 0,
    swipeToSlide: true,
    autoplay: false,
    arrows: false,
    lazyLoad: true,
  };
  const slide = useRef();
  function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
  }
  const addOrRemoveLike = async (postId) => {
    const isLike = myLikes.filter((like) => like.user._id === user._id).length > 0;
    try {
      await axios({
        method: 'PUT',
        url: `${process.env.SERVER}/posts/${isLike ? 'unliked' : 'liked'}/${postId}`,
        withCredentials: true,
      });
      if (!isLike) {
        const users = [item.user._id];
        if (item.user._id !== user._id) socket.emit('newnotification', { users });
      }
      isLike ? setMyLikes((prev) => prev.filter((p) => p.user._id !== user._id)) : setMyLikes((prev) => ([{ user }, ...prev]));
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  const handleScroll = (direction) => {
    const { current } = scrollRef;

    setCurrentItem((prev) => (prev + 1) % (item.files.length));
    const scrollAmount = current.offsetWidth ? current.offsetWidth : 100;

    if (direction === 'left') {
      current.scrollLeft -= scrollAmount;
    } else {
      current.scrollLeft += scrollAmount;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className={`flex-1 w-[60%] border-b  gap-3
    md:w-full ${isModal ? 'flex-row' : 'flex-col'} flex items-center justify-start`}
    >
      {/* Top */}
      <div className=" flex w-full flex-row items-center gap-3 ">
        <div className="border overflow-hidden rounded-full w-14 h-14 sm:w-10 sm:h-10 flex items-center justify-center bg-nft-gray-2 dark:bg-nft-gray-3">
          {
            item.user.logo.length > 0
              ? <img src={`${process.env.SERVER}/${item.user.logo}`} className="w-full h-full object-cover" />
              : <UserOutlined className="text-2xl sm:text-xl" />
          }
        </div>
        <div className="flex-1 flex flex-row items-center justify-between gap-2">
          <div className="flex-1 flex flex-col justify-start ">
            <Link href={`user/${item.user.username}`}>
              {/* eslint-disable-next-line jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid */}
              <a className="text-blue-600 dark:text-blue-500 font-medium"> {item.user.username} </a>
            </Link>
            <div className="w-10/12">
              <h1 className="text-xs font-thin">
                {item.location}
              </h1>
              <h1 className="text-xs font-thin">
                <span className="font-medium">posted: </span>
                {calculateTime(item.date, t)}
              </h1>

            </div>

          </div>
          {
            user._id === item.user._id && (
            <div>
              <DeleteOutlined className="transition-all duration-500 text-xl cursor-pointer hover:text-nft-black-1 dark:hover:text-nft-gray-1" />
            </div>
            )
          }

        </div>
      </div>
      {/* Bottom */}
      <div className="flex-1 w-full flex flex-col gap-1">
        {/* FIles */}
        <div
          className="flex-2 w-full border bg-nft-gray-1 dark:bg-nft-black-1
        relative
        "
        >
          <ArrowLeftOutlined
            className="absolute top-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 left-0 -translate-x-1/2
          bg-nft-black-1 text-white text-xl flex justify-center items-center p-1 rounded-full cursor-pointer
          hover:text-2xl transition-all duration-500
          dark:bg-nft-gray-3 z-[5]
          "
            onClick={() => slide.current.slickPrev()}
          />
          <ArrowRightOutlined
            className="absolute top-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 right-0 translate-x-1/2
          bg-nft-black-1 text-white text-xl flex justify-center items-center p-1 rounded-full cursor-pointer
          hover:text-2xl transition-all duration-500
          dark:bg-nft-gray-3 z-[5]
          "
            onClick={() => slide.current.slickNext()}
          />
          <div className="h-[70%] w-full border bg-nft-gray-1 dark:bg-nft-black-1">
            <div className="relative h-full">
              <Slider {...settings} ref={slide}>
                {
                item.files.map((i, item) => (
                  <div key={item} className="w-full h-full flex justify-center items-center ">
                    {
                      i.type.startsWith('image')
                        ? (
                          <img
                            onLoad={() => imageLoaded(i.path)}
                            src={`${process.env.SERVER}/${i.path}`}
                            className={` object-cover
                                ${imageLoading.filter((t) => t.path === i.path).length > 0 && 'hidden'}
                              `}
                            alt="image"
                          />
                        )

                        : (
                          <video
                            src={`${process.env.SERVER}/${i.path}`}
                            className="object-contain"
                            controls
                            controlsList="nodownload"
                          />
                        )
                    }
                  </div>
                ))
            }

              </Slider>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        {/* Statistics */}
        <div className="flex-1 flex flex-col gap-2">
          <div className="flex w-full flex-row justify-between items-center">
            <div className=" flex  flex-row gap-3 transition-all duration-500 items-center justify-start relative">
              {
            myLikes.filter((like) => like.user._id === user._id).length > 0
              ? (
                <HeartFilled
                  className={`text-2xl text-red-500 dark:text-red-600 ${user.id === item.user._id && 'cursor-pointer'}`}
                  onClick={() => addOrRemoveLike(item._id)}
                />
              )
              : (
                <HeartOutlined
                  className="text-2xl"
                  onClick={() => addOrRemoveLike(item._id)}
                />
              )
          }
              {
            myLikes.length > 0 && (
            <div
              className={`text-sm font-medium ${user._id === item.user._id && 'cursor-pointer '}`}
              onClick={() => { setIsOpen(user._id === item.user._id); }}
            >
              {numberWithCommas(myLikes.length).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',')} likes
            </div>
            )
          }
            </div>
            <div className="text-sm relative before:content-[''] before:absolute before:block before:w-full before:h-[2px]
              before:bottom-0 before:left-0 before:bg-blue-500 dark:before:bg-blue-600
              before:hover:scale-x-100 before:scale-x-0 before:origin-top-left
              before:transition-all before:ease-in-out before:duration-300
              cursor-pointer text-blue-500 dark:text-blue-600
              "
            >Go to this post
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="flex flex-row gap-2 flex-wrap">
            {item.tags.map((i) => (
              <div key={i} className="flex flex-row items-center bg-blue-500 px-1 text-white dark:bg-blue-600 transition-all duration-500">
                <p className="text-sm ">#{i}</p>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
          <div className="flex flex-row">
            <p className="text-sm truncate whitespace-nowrap overflow-hidden">{item.description}</p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      {
        isOpen && (
        <Modal

          setClose={setIsOpen}
          header="Likes"
        >
          {
            myLikes.map((i, index) => (
              <div
                key={index}
                className={` ${index !== myLikes.length - 1 && 'mb-2'} flex flex-row justify-center items-center cursor-pointer`}
              >
                <div className="w-full flex-1 p-2 shadow dark:bg-nft-black-2 flex flex-row items-center justify-between">

                  <div className="flex flex-row gap-5 flex-1 items-center">
                    <div className="h-10 w-10 rounded-full flex justify-center items-center bg-nft-gray-1 dark:bg-nft-black-1 overflow-hidden">
                      {
                        i.user.logo.length > 0
                          ? (
                            <img
                              src={`${process.env.SERVER}/${i.user.logo}`}
                              className="w-full h-full object-cover"
                            />
                          )
                          : <UserOutlined />
                        }

                    </div>
                    <div className="flex flex-col items-start justify-between">
                      <p>{i.user.username}</p>
                      {((i.user.firstName.length > 0) || (i.user.lastName.length > 0))
                        && (
                        <h1
                          className="font-medium text-sm"
                        >{`${i.user.firstName} ${i.user.lastName}`}
                        </h1>
                        )}
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
            ))
        }
        </Modal>
        )
      }

    </div>
  );
};

export default Post;
```

I use `react-slick` for carousel. But `height` dont get. I parent div heigth `h-[70%]`. When I see without images everything good but after add `react slick` carousel images height increased. How do this?

Comment: From memory slick will change the CSS of the top level div, so you might be losing your flex. Try wrapping each slide in a plain div.

Comment: React slick Slider dont get parent height